# How to extract attributes from elements identified with reference to other elements selected through xpath from multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I'm having an issue when trying to select data from a class. What I need to do is get the third TD (the report name) of every class (named "odd" or "even"), then compare that to a string variable in python (which is the name of the report submitted, for example "Name of Report 2 (scrubbed)"), and if it matches I need to grab the value of the first td. I just need to be able to grab that number using that report name in the third td. Any ideas? I tried CSS selectors like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class, 'data') and contains(., 'Name of Report 1 (scrubbed)')]")
```

But I keep getting garbage put into the string var in python. Thanks!

```
<tr class="odd">
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><input type='checkbox' name='report' value='4933047'/></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 65px;"><a href="#" onclick="getReportDetails('4933047')">4933047</a></td>
<td>Name of Report 1 (scrubbed)</td>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">'PRO_DET'</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 65px;">2018-05-19</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 95px;">2018-04-04</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">Complete</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
<td style="text-align: center; width: 25px;"><input type='checkbox' name='report' value='4933041'/></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 65px;"><a href="#" onclick="getReportDetails('4933041')">4933041</a></td>
<td>Name of Report 2 (scrubbed)</td>
<td></td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">'PRO_DET'</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 65px;">2018-05-19</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 95px;">2018-04-04</td>
<td style="text-align: center; width: 60px;">Complete</td></tr>
```

Comment: `compare that to a variable` which variable?

Comment: I'd be comparing the values of td[3] to a string, which is variable based on the name of the report submitted (pulled from elsewhere). In this example, it would be be "Name of Report 2 (scrubbed)", but it's always different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML provided to get the third `<td>` node of every class *odd* or *even* and then compare that to a string variable and if it matches to grab the value of the first td, you can write a function and pass the *String* to be matched as follows :

```
def test_me(myString):
    myList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='odd' or @class='even']//following-sibling::td[3]")
    for item in myList:
        if item.text == myString:
            print(item.find_element_by_xpath(".//preceding::td[2]/input").get_attribute("value"))
```

---

### Update

As per your counter question here are the details :

### `following-sibling` keyword in *xpath* :

- Example :

  ```
  (“//*[@class=’o2-app-header’]//following-sibling::a”)
  ```
- Description : The technique is used to locate the sibling elements of a particular node.
- Explanation : The xpath expression gets the all the sibling elements of the element located using “//*[@class=’o2-app-header’]”.

### `preceding` keyword in *xpath* :

- Example :

  ```
  (“//body/preceding::*”)
  ```
- Description : The technique is used to locate all the preceding elements of a particular element.
- Explanation : The xpath expression returns all the preceding elements from BODY tag.

Comment: Your solution works great! I'm pretty new to this,would you mind explaining the "following-sibling" as well as the two colons? I would like to know their usage and meanings please. Same with "preceding", if you're willing. Your help is very VERY much appreciated, I've been banging my head on this for two days. Thanks!

Comment: @pxl Check out my answer update and let me know if any queries

Comment: Excellent explanations, thanks so much!! If I had enough karma I'd upvote you (:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I am no python expert and mainly do C#, but let me give it a go and see if it helps you.

Assuming you ALWAYS need the third td under a tr, first thing you are going to need to do is create an object of the tr. As there are many rows, you are going to have to make a loop.

```
tableRow = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr")
```

This will return a list of elements which are table rows (assuming these are the only rows on the page). Now for every row you want to get the third td element, correct? And you only want to do this for the rows which are odd or even?

So you make a for loop on your list.

```
for el in tableRow:

    thirdColumn = el.find_element_by_xpath("(//td)[3]")
    thirdColumnText = thirdColumn.text


    if "yourtext" in thirdColumnText:

      firstColumn = el.find_element_by_xpath("(//td)[1]")

      firstColumnInput = firstColumn.find_element_by_xpath("//input")
      firstColumnInputValue = firstColumnInput.get_attribute("value")

    //here you can assert if the firstColumnInputValue contains thirdColumnText
```

Then you can use your value of first column as you please.

So to explain what we are doing, in short:

- First we are creating tableRow (which has class odd or even)
- Then for every tableRow we have, we are first checking the text of the third column.
- If the text of third column contains your python variable
- We are getting the value attribute of the  within the first column
- Once we have the latter, we are going to check if this value contains the value of the third column. I don't exactly know how they are formatted, but you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: I tried something similar, but I keep getting this `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="01c47c3575481e0341d96cb8ffc25c0c", element="0.25009769383057434-1411")>` as the text from the elements in td[3]. Same result with yours. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you open console in chrome (f12) on your webpage, typ $x("//tr/(//td)[3]") and see if you get a column with the text in it? It could also be a timing issue. Just for trial/error purposes, could you check if a small thread sleep helps after page load? Maybe the table isnt completely loaded in the DOM

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to enter that in, so I put it in the console, tried to find it via ctrl + f, and the style filter. No dice. Do you need more of the page to give better info? It would take a while to scrub the info from it (internal application). The page loads all the way for sure, I used a 3sec sleep to make sure it has time to populate.